# Can we use Springboot with multimodule for microservices

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, multi-module

As Springboot multimodule produces single fat jar will that be good idea to use spring boot multimodule project for microservices

Comment: of course you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Actually it is a very good idea to use the multimodule project.
Below are some advantages of that:

1. Gives clarity about the code and project module
2. Decouples the layer.
3. Easy to modify/add the module. Suppose your persistence module is already implemented with Couchbase and now you wanted to switch to Mongo DB then you just need to change the persistence module(dependency, code, configuration) not other parts of a project.
4. Easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I have one more doubt we will getting individual jars right for each module.We will not be getting any single fat jar right as we are packaging to pom so no single jar right we will be getting only individual jars of modules.

Comment: you are getting jar in every module because it's packaging type is jar while creating the module. you need to use maven assembly plugin or shade plugin to create the fat and executable jar. Also you can use the spring boot plugin for executable jar. e.g.<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   </plugin>

Answer (score 0):

No, I believe. Actually, it is bad design to generate single fat jar for multimodule project in Spring Boot. Suppose, we have multimodule project having 3 sub-modules for different microservices. Then each module will have its individual pom right? that we need to refer in main project's pom as module. Now, assume anyhow we are able to define packaging in main module pom as single fat jar for all the sub-modules. Then, you are not following the microservices architecture guidlines. It will be a kind of monolithic architecture, because all your services are there in a single unit (a jar). Although it would be easy to maintain, but difficuilt to configure through Jenkins pipelines. I mean you have to customize your Jenkins pipelines.

You may refer following url for more details : https://thebasictechinfo.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-microservices-architecture-spring-cloud-netflix-oss